# Eaten by a computer

Tags: identify-this-movie

Flashback from my childhood in the 80s, but I was laying in bed last night trying to go to sleep when I remember this blip of a scene from a movie. Something like this guy falls back into a computer (probably a server) whereby he was engulfed in circuits, wires, etc and this happened right in front of his gf, or some friend, something along these lines. He walks back away from the computer, but now a cyborg. And I believe he is now also evil.

It kept me up for most of the night. I wish I had more details, but this is all of the flashback I have and I **know** I didn't just make this up, lol.

Comment: [Superman 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpTHrdemfQo)?

Comment: No see, why couldn't I remember that last night? I would have had 3+ more hours of sleep!

Comment: Your mistake was not asking it here. Thinking is for suckers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Superman 3. You can see the relevant scene below.

Lex's Sister falls into the "Ultimate Computer", turns into a cyborg and for some inexplicable reason also becomes evil...

Comment: Now I know why the OP was up last night: it was a *nightmare*.

Comment: Ah, yes...I was there opening night for Richard Pryor.

Comment: Wow. That movie looks truly terrible.

Comment: @BrettFromLA - It's not "Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone" bad, but it's pretty bad.

Comment: @Richard I've heard of that movie, but have studiously avoided it.

Comment: @BrettFromLA - You should watch it. It gives you a whole new perspective on films. For the rest of your life, whenever you're watching a bad film you can always think "*Heck, **at least I'm not watching Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone***"

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the movie Lawnmower Man.

Comment: Fun fact:  This movie was supposedly based on a Stephen King short story. But the short story "Lawnmower Man" is about a hired gardener who eat the grass and worships Pan. It has noooooooooooooothing to do with virtual reality. Not a single thing.